# C-d in java-mode not being overwritten by .emacs file

Tags: key-bindings, configuration-files

So I have a custom .emacs file that I have a series of key strokes bound to.  The specific key stroke that I'm speaking of is `C-d` which I have bound to `left-word` via the line `(global-set-key (kbd "C-d") 'left-word)`

This works fine for any major mode that I've used except for `java-mode`.  For some reason, when I'm in `java-mode`, the key becomes bound to `c-electric-delete-forward`.

Anyone have any idea as to why this key binding override works in all major modes except for Java?

Comment: The global keymap is the *lowest priority* keymap in Emacs, so if any other active keymap binds `C-d` your global binding does not take effect. Presumably `java-mode-map` does so. You're probably looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/683425/globally-override-key-binding-in-emacs but I recommend also reading https://www.masteringemacs.org/article/mastering-key-bindings-emacs

Comment: This question is likely a duplicate.